# Why is the "POST" method not passing the "type=file" variable, please?

Tags: post, file-upload, html5-video

My code was uploading video files, but after I extended the form it stopped uploading. All the other variables were passed OK but not the file variable was blank.

I tried comparing the upload logic with similar examples on the web but could not see what I had changed to cause it to fail. In the listing below I have removed all the irrelevant code. When this code runs it returns "Error".

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
if (isset($_FILES['urlvideo'])) {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['urlvideo']['tmp_name'], "{$_FILES['urlvideo']['name']}");
} else {
  echo('Error');
  exit();
}
?>  
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="videotest.php"
          method="post"
         enctype="multipart/form-data">   
      Upload video:
      <input type="file" name="urlvideo" /><br>
      <input type="submit"
            value="Submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
if ( $_POST ) {
    if (isset($_FILES['urlvideo'])) {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['urlvideo']['tmp_name'], "{$_FILES['urlvideo']['name']}");
    } else {
      echo('Error');
      exit();
    }
}
?>  
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="testup.php"
          method="post"
         enctype="multipart/form-data">   
        <input type="hidden" name="method" value="post" /><!-- for check $_POST before if isset $_FILES-->
      Upload video:
      <input type="file" name="urlvideo" /><br>
      <input type="submit"
            value="Submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

it is because you put **if ( isset( $_FILES** before showing the form.

Comment: Thank you, I copied and pasted the code but I still cannot get it to copy. I thought it may be copying on top of it's self but the created and modified dates are unaltered. I altered the POST to GET to see what is was passing and it is only passing the filename with no path.

Comment: you just add input type="hidden" with some random name and value.
next,
cloak "if (isset($_FILES" with if ( $_POST ) {...} to make it work when there is hidden data send to php.
i confirm that all your upload code works fine. just input hidden and if $_POST as i show you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It turns out that my code changes had not caused the problem and of course your code worked. I had created more test data with file sizes > the default upload limit in my php.ini (2MB). Being new to web development I was unaware of this parameter. My web application works again. So much time expended, still it is a lesson learned and I will now go through all the PHP and Apache parameters to make sure I do not get tripped up again by something similar.